# how do I encrypt my home foulder on ubuntu 20.04 after install?

Tags: 20.04, encryption

I installed ubuntu 20.04 and I am trying to duel boot. So I want to encrypt my home Ubuntu fouler after install how do I do that?
according to https://www.howtogeek.com/116032/how-to-encrypt-your-home-folder-after-installing-ubuntu/ I can use the program ecryptfs-utils cryptsetup but it is not comparable with Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Woah weird. I just logged onto askubuntu to ask the exact same question 2 hours after you asked it

Comment: cryptsetup and ecryptfs are two separate tools. cryptsetup is very much compatible with Ubuntu 20.04, and sufficient to encrypt a home partition on its own. Are you planning to put your home partition on a separate partition, or is it part of one unique Ubuntu partition?